# How can add more space if NSData < fixed size in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, byte, nsdata

I have a problem: I used below codes to get data from **NSData**, but I want to get data from **[0;2048] bytes**. If my data > 2048**strong text**, it can run fine but if my `data < 2048`, it'll wrong. So that I want to add more some space at last if my `data < 2048` to enough **2048 bytes**. Can you help me? Thanks so much.

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[arrayText UTF8String] length:[arrayText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSData *datawrite = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2048)];
```

Above code is work fine if `data > 2048 bytes`, if `data < 2048 bytes` , my MAC app hangs. Please give me any suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: `NSData * datawrite = [ data subdataWithRange:(NSRange){ 0, MIN( 2048, data.length ) } ]`

Comment: (Also it's Mac, not MAC.) And it's probably not a hang, you're probably seeing an out of range exception.

Comment: @nielsbot: Your code is only get from 0 to 2048 bytes if mydata > 2048, it is right but mydata < 2048, it is not correct. Thanks

Comment: huh? You said your app hangs if data is less than 2048 bytes. So I wrote code to get up to 2048 bytes, unless data is shorter in which case you will get up to the length of data. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, if mydata < 2048, it's an out of range exception. So that i want to add more space at last to enough 2048 byes

Comment: I tried your code but when mydata is shorter 2048 bytes, datawrite is still < 2048 bytes, exactly datawrite get bytes from mydata

Comment: Why do you need that datawrite has 2048 bytes? (Is this related to your previous question, which you deleted when I posted an answer?)

Comment: @MartinR: sorry for my delete prvious qeustion, i want to write data to file and size of file is equals 2048 bytes

Comment: nielsbot's answer should work. It would just have been nice to know why my suggested solution did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this will copy as many bytes as are available (up to 2048) from `data`. If the result is < 2048 bytes, the new data will be padded to 2048 bytes.

```
NSMutableData * datawrite = [ data subdataWithRange:(NSRange){ 0, MIN( 2048, data.length ) } ] mutableCopy ] ;
[ datawrite setLength:2048 ] ;
```

BUT: Can you tell us the broader application? This seems like a strange use case and I'd like to understand more.

Comment: Thanks but when mydata < 2048 bytes, it added 00000 000000 000000 at last datawrite. How can i add 20202020 at last to enough 2048 bytes? My app is write file with fixed size is 2048 bytes.

Comment: Use `memset`. Why does your string need to be filled with spaces?

Comment: memset is very useful in my case. I sovled my problem. thanks much