# How can append Data to NSmutableData in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xmldocument

I want to add new NSdata = x20 (ASCII) , it's a space at last in NSMutableData to enough fixed byes. Example: NSmuatabledata has 400 bytes, but i need this NSMutableData has 600 bytes. So that i want to add 200 byes (x20 in HEX) at last this nsmutableData. How can i do that? please help me. thanks in advance

```
// write xmlDoc to file
NSData* xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePreserveAll];
NSLog(@"xmlData %@",xmlData);
NSMutableData * datawrite = [xmlData mutableCopy ] ;
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // i dont know how to add x20 (hex) to this array 
[datawrite appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: what u tried so far?...please paste your code...

Comment: This looks **very similar** to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525103/how-can-add-more-space-if-nsdata-fixed-size-in-cocoa (for which you accepted an answer).

Comment: @MartinR: My previous question is used to text file. Now, my problem is for XML file. I tried code in previous question but it not right.

Comment: @iOSCoder: i updated my code but i don't know how to add x20 (hex) to array. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: @JosonDaniel: nielsbot's answer to that question shows how to extend the size of NSMutableData, and in a comment he also suggested to use memset to fill the memory with spaces. - What else do you need?

Comment: @MartinR: memset?? Is it used to? Can you tell me more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableData *datawrite = ...
NSUInteger oldLength = [datawrite length];
NSUInteger newLength = 600;
if (newLength > oldLength ) {
    // extend mutable data object:
    [datawrite setLength:newLength];

    // fill appended bytes with space characters:
    char *bytes = [datawrite mutableBytes];
    memset(bytes + oldLength, ' ', newLength - oldLength);
}
```